# Dynamically assign a title in an element using the value of h2 element

Tags: html, jquery, css

Is there a way to dynamically assign a title attribute in an element so that when the page loads it automatically be assign with a title attribute with the value of an h2 element on top of it?

I'm guessing that it's possible with jQuery/javascript but i am not too sure how.

Here's the code i started with:

```
<a><h2>Website</h2></a>

<div class="indent">
 1st Div<br><br>
  <div class="contentbox">
  Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Website"</b>.
  </div>
  
</div>

<a><h2>Portal</h2></a>

<div class="indent">
 2nd Div<br><br>
  <div class="contentbox">
  Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Portal"</b>
  </div>
  
</div>

<a><h2>Stackoverflow</h2></a>

<div class="indent">
 3rd Div<br><br>
  <div class="contentbox">
  Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Stackoverflow"</b>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

And the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Rgohing/1yrzhpxw/19/

Thank you in advance, I would greatly appreciate any help that i can get.

Comment: What element are you trying to add the title to? Also, you have tagged css - how does CSS come into qhat you would like to do?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to add the h2 value inside the div.contentbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The code you need is very dependent on the structure of your html, so I have assumed the following:**

- Your `<div class="contentbox">` will always be in a container ( in your example, its `<div class="indent">` but the code will work no matter what the class is)
- The `<h2>` will always be surrounded by an `<a>` tag

**Based on this, the jQuery you need to get the heading is:**

```
$(function() {
    $('div.contentbox').attr('title', function() {    
        return $(this).parent().prevAll("a:first").text();
    });
});
```

**This works as follows:**

1. For each div with class `contentbox`...
2. this code gets its parent (e.g. the container div with class `indent`)...
3. then gets all previous siblings until it finds the first one that is an `<a>` tag...
4. and returns the text it contains (which is actually the heading text).
5. The returned value is added as the `title` on the div with class `contentbox`

Here it is in a working snippet that also outputs the heading text to the console so we know its getting the right text.

```js
$(function() {
   $('div.contentbox').attr('title', function() {
     var headingtext = $(this).parent().prevAll("a:first").text();

     console.log(headingtext);  // just for testing - output the text it finds   
     return headingtext;
   });
});
```

```css
.indent
{
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a><h2>Website</h2></a>

<div class="indent">
 1st Div<br><br>
  <div class="contentbox">
  Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Website"</b>.
  </div>
  
</div>

<a><h2>Portal</h2></a>

<div class="indent">
 2nd Div<br><br>
  <div class="contentbox">
  Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Portal"</b>
  </div>
  
</div>

<a><h2>Stackoverflow</h2></a>

<div class="indent">
 3rd Div<br><br>
  <div class="contentbox">
  Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Stackoverflow"</b>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for analyzing, and explaining what's actually happening in the script. :)

Comment: @RenzC.Gohing Glad to help! If you understand what's happening in the script, then you will be better able to make changes to it if you need to in future e.g. your html changes :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to assign element's html/text to title attribute. like below

```
$('h2').each(function(){
    var val = $(this).text();
    $(this).parent('a').siblings('.indent').children('.contentbox').attr("title", val);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need the value of the h2 to be inside the div.contentbox, any ideas?

Comment: You can try closest property. $('h2').each(function(){
    var val = $(this).text();
    $(this).closest('.indent').children('.contentbox').attr("title",val);
})

Comment: exact code will be like 
            $(this).parent('a').siblings('.indent').children('.contentbox').attr("title", val);

Comment: That script assigns the h2 value "Stackoverflow" to all div.contentbox attribute. We're getting close!

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this using javascript.Just add you h2 tag inside indent div.Below is the fully working code.

```
<div class="indent">
    <a>
        <h2>Website</h2>
    </a>
    1st Div<br><br>
    <div class="contentbox">
        Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title
        that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Website"</b>.
    </div>

</div>



<div class="indent">
    <a>
        <h2>Portal</h2>
    </a>
    2nd Div<br><br>
    <div class="contentbox">
        Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title
        that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Portal"</b>
    </div>

</div>



<div class="indent">
    <a>
        <h2>Stackoverflow</h2>
    </a>
    3rd Div<br><br>
    <div class="contentbox">
        Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title
        that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's
        <b>title="Stackoverflow"</b>
    </div>

</div>
<script>
    let contentbox = document.querySelectorAll('.contentbox');
    for (i = 0; i < contentbox.length; i++) {
        contentbox[i].setAttribute('title', contentbox[i].parentElement.firstElementChild.innerText);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It does work too. However, the structure of the html elements should be untouched.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to make the changes at the source, meaning editing the HTML or code generating the HTML. A client-side approach should be a last resort.

Let's say you wanted to add the attribute to the `div.indent` element. The code to add a `title` attribute using jQuery would be:

```
$('div.indent').attr('title', function() {
    return $(this).prev().text();
});
```

```js
$(function() {
   $('div.indent').attr('title', function() {
       return $(this).prev().text();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a><h2>Website</h2></a>

<div class="indent">
 1st Div<br><br>
  <div class="contentbox">
  Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Website"</b>.
  </div>
  
</div>

<a><h2>Portal</h2></a>

<div class="indent">
 2nd Div<br><br>
  <div class="contentbox">
  Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Portal"</b>
  </div>
  
</div>

<a><h2>Stackoverflow</h2></a>

<div class="indent">
 3rd Div<br><br>
  <div class="contentbox">
  Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Stackoverflow"</b>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

If, however the goal is to add `title` attribute to the inner `div` here is how you might approach that:

```
$('div.contentbox').attr('title', function() {
    return $(this).closest('div.indent').prev().text();
});
```

```js
$(function() {
   $('div.contentbox').attr('title', function() {
       return $(this).closest('div.indent').prev().text();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a><h2>Website</h2></a>

<div class="indent">
 1st Div<br><br>
  <div class="contentbox">
  Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Website"</b>.
  </div>
  
</div>

<a><h2>Portal</h2></a>

<div class="indent">
 2nd Div<br><br>
  <div class="contentbox">
  Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Portal"</b>
  </div>
  
</div>

<a><h2>Stackoverflow</h2></a>

<div class="indent">
 3rd Div<br><br>
  <div class="contentbox">
  Content of div with a class of contentbox, this div should dynamically be assign with the attribute of title that has the value of the h2 element that was on top of it. For this instance, it's <b>title="Stackoverflow"</b>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank, I just tested this and it seems to work fine, but the title attribute needs to be in div.contentbox without changing the structure of the elements.

Comment: I actually tried to modify the script hoping it could work but unfortunately doesn't:

$('div.contentbox').attr('title', function() {
    return $(this).prev("h2").value();
});

It appears to be only searching the immediate element on top of it.